# Warning C4267 in Visual Studio: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const _Elem', possible loss of data

Tags: c++

I am getting the warning from this function:

```
std::pair<size_t, size_t> GetSection(const string& s1, const string& s2) {
        size_t top_section = s1.find(s2 + ":");
        size_t bottom_section = s1.find(s1.length() - top_section);

        return std::make_pair(top_section, bottom_section);
}
```

I don't understand what conversion is occurring that is causing the problem.
I also understand that this function can be written like so:

```
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> GetSection(const string& s1, const string& s2) {
        size_t top_section = s1.find(s2 + ":");
        size_t bottom_section = top_section + s2.length() + 1;

        return std::make_pair(top_section, bottom_section);
}
```

I just want to know why I am getting this warning.

Comment: `s1.find(s1.length() - top_section);` What is this supposed to `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this function call:

```
s1.find(s1.length() - top_section);
```

The argument `s1.length() - top_section` is a *number* of type `size_t`, but the `find` method is supposed to take in a *string* or *character* to search for.

(Specifically, because C++ always assumes you mean what you say, it's trying to convert the `size_t` to a `char`, but that causes a loss of precision since the `char` type is only 8 bits wide.)